# Encryption node Js

Tags: android, node.js

Hi this is my encryption code i'm trying to decrypt the code in Android via json. I can decrypt this code in node js. But when i tried to decrypt in android error occured so any one suggest me where the problem is occur whether in my node js code or android.

```
app.post('/insert',  function (req,res){
        var data = {
            userId:req.body.fname,
            firstName:req.body.fname
        };


                var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes128', 'a password');
                 data.firstName = cipher.update(data.firstName, 'utf8','base64' );
                data.firstName += cipher.final('base64');
                console.log(data);

         con.query("insert into md5 set ?",[data], function (err,rows){
            if(err) throw err;  
                res.send("Value has been inserted");
            })
             console.log(data.firstName);
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

When we are using any kind of Encryption and Decryption into our System (Including DB) our all clients should be having similar credentials to parsing that message.

Lets say we have Backend, Web and Mobile Apps(Android/iPhone). So what backend Encrypt the message with whatever credentials All other client can be having same credentials to decrypt that message.

Here i am suggesting that AES Use **256 with Predefine IV and KEY**. And **Crypto** is very famous library that will having the feature in all the platform. I did with Node.js.

**Snippet for Encrypt Text:**

```
encryptText: function(text) {
        var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(Constant.algo, Constant.key, Constant.iv);
        var result = cipher.update(text, "utf8", 'base64');
        result += cipher.final('base64');
        return result;
    },
```

**Snippet for Decrypt Text:**

```
decryptText: function(text) {
        console.log(text);

        var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(Constant.algo, Constant.key, Constant.iv);
        var result = decipher.update(text, 'base64');
        result += decipher.final();
        return result;
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can incrypt using salt and hash
first generate salt

```
   var salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64');
```

Second generate encrypted password

```
   var password = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, new Buffer(this.salt, 'base64'), 10000, 64, 'sha1').toString('base64');
```

Perform login with same method.

Answer (score 0):

i recommand using the Crypto-JS libraray: `npm install crypto-js`

and there are multiple ways to encrypt a string in crypto-js looking at the example think this would be most appropriate

```
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

// Encrypt
var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('my message', 'secret key 123').toString();

// Decrypt
var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, 'secret key 123');
var originalText = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
 
console.log(originalText); // 'my message'
```

so the final solution would look something like this

```
app.post('/insert',  function (req,res){
  var data = {
    userId:req.body.fname,
    firstName:req.body.fname
  };


  const encryptedFirstName = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data.firstName, 'password'); // encrypting the `firstName` gotten from the `data` object
  data.firstName = encryptedFirstName // setting the `firstName` in the `data` object to encrypted value
  console.log(data);

  con.query("insert into md5 set ?",[data], function (err,rows){
     if(err) throw err;  
         res.send("Value has been inserted");
     })
     console.log(data.firstName);
     })
```